# Reading necessary bytes

Tags: c#, string, byte, elm327

is it possible to read only last two bytes from a string. For example I receive 41 0C 34 from a stream socket, and I only need 34. In what way I can do this. Here is my code:

```
   public string ReadSensor(ISensor sensor)
    {

        if (ConnectedPort == null)
            return null;
        if (client.Connected)
        {

            string PIDhex = (sensor.GetValue(this)).ToString("x2"); ;

           string PID = Convert.ToString("01"+PIDhex+"\r");

           byte[] byteAir = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Convert.ToString(PID));

           stream.Write(byteAir, 0, byteAir.Length);

           byte[] MessageProt = new byte[8];
           stream.Read(MessageProt,0,MessageProt.Length);
           var str = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(MessageProt);

           string output = Convert.ToString(str);
           return output;
           }
```

Note: I need only 34 as I need to convert it to a decimal value and than implement it into an equation. thanks :)

Comment: strings have characters; streams have bytes; strings can be *encoded* to bytes, but there isn't a direct map between the two unless you first define the encoding; it isn't clear what you want to do here - you can *skip* bytes (by reading them but not processing them), but you can't get the "last n" bytes unless you buffer at least n bytes (presumably in a  circular buffer) and wait until you get to the end of the stream

Comment: btw: your reading code is not safe; you could have read 1 byte, 0 bytes, anything up to `MessageProt.Length` bytes; you could have received one half of the logical message, with the other half still en-route (split packets, buffers, etc) - basically: this is **not** how you talk to a socket if you want it to work robustly

Comment: Unfortunately I came to a point that when I try to read at a second read stream operation, some bytes are confused or not showing correctly.  I am trying a diiferent approach which can be seen below:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just "not read" bytes from a socket.

So, read the entire string and select the characters you want as explained in [Extract only right most n letters from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722334/extract-only-right-most-n-letters-from-a-string):

```
string lastTwo = input.Substring(input.Length - 2);
```

But as [Marc points out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30594216/reading-necessary-bytes/30594274#comment49257651_30594216), your reading code won't work properly. It's a coincidence it works now, but it can fail miserably. See [What does Filestream.Read return value mean? How to read data in chunks and process it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5075924/what-does-filestream-read-return-value-mean-how-to-read-data-in-chunks-and-proc) to call `Read()` until you read the number of bytes you expect.